# mongoDB Aggregate By Date and another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to run an aggregation by a date field and offer id field. I have the following code which produces the sum of all offers viewed for each month.

```
db.useroffers.aggregate(

    {$project: {date: {
        month: {$month: "$viewdate"},
        year: {$year: "$viewdate"},
    }}},
    {$limit: {offer_id: {$in: [101,102,103,104,105,106]}}},
    {$group: {_id: {offer_id: "$offer_id", date: "$date"}, views: {$sum: 1}}}
)
```

However, I need to group by $month-$year and show the sum of each offer viewed to the limited offer_ids.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but it looks like `$limit` should be `$match` in your `aggregate` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question would be better with a sample document, however it mostly seems you have some of your terms mixed around.

Firstly [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is for reshaping of the document in the pipeline. While you have *changed* the structure of the date to what you want, you have omitted the other fields that you want to use later in other pipeline phases. The only other field that is *implicitly* included is `_id`. So you need to explicitly declare the fields that you want.

Secondly [$limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) takes a single numeric argument only, representing the number of documents in the collection to keep. It generally only makes sense to use this if you are testing a very large source and want a subset until your whole pipeline is complete, or after sorting a final result where you just want to return a certain number of entries.

For the sort of *selection* you are trying to do here, you need the [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator, which you can use in the way you are attempting to *match* a set of `offer_id` values.

```
db.useroffers.aggregate(
    // Match first
    {$match: {offer_id: {$in: [101,102,103,104,105,106]}}},

    // Change the document. You could also do this in group
    {$project: {
        date: {
            month: {$month: "$viewdate"},
            year: {$year: "$viewdate"},
        },
        offer_id: 1,
        views: 1
    }},

    // Group by "date" and "offer_id"
    {$group: {
        _id: { date: "$date", offer_id: "$offer_id"},
        views: {$sum: 1}
    }},

    // Nicer output
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        date: {$concat: [
            {$substr: ["$_id.date.month", 0, 2]},
            "-",
            {$substr: ["$_id.date.year", 0, 4]}
        ]},
        offer_id: "$_id.offer_id,
        views: 1
    }}
)
```

Comment: Neil,thanks for your great response. What I trying to achieve is the following: [{01/2013: {101: 16 //this the sum of views for this offer, 102: 8, 103:...}},{02/2013:{101: 4, 102: 7, 103:...}},...]. I tried your code but I am getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" error. I am trying to debug right now.